# Octonion algebras over number fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, number-fields, octonions, quaternion-algebras

Is there any textbook or paper about Arithmetic of Octonion Algebras or Octonion Algebras constructed over number fields? I know [J. Voight](https://math.dartmouth.edu/~jvoight/quat-book.pdf) book and [K. Martin](https://math.dartmouth.edu/~jvoight/quat-book.pdf) notes about quaternion algebras but I was thinking about a generalization using Octonions.

More than that: Is it possible to define Orders and Maximal Orders over an octonion algebra? Or these concepts just make sense over associative algebras?

Comment: Possibly you'll find information here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.09979 (*Composition algebras* by A. Elduque)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was simultaneously asked at Mathematics (no cross-posting, please). If after a week there is no answer there, it may be asked here. (Update: there was an answer at math.se: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3503269/octonion-algebras-over-number-fields)